# Calling multiple time getDatabase() MongoDB

Tags: c#, mongodb, performance, wcf

This is my first post, i'm sorry if i do something wrong.
So, here's my problem, as a beginner in mongoDB on C#.
I plan to have multiple Databases, one for each project. A project contains multiple dataset which will be handled with Collections.
On my application, every function calls a WCF client which will query the right database. I want to know if multiple "getDatabase(db)" can have bad effects on performances, or i can call it as much/often as i want ?

Comment: No bad effect. It's just switching a namespace. That's it.

Comment: @NeilLunn Thank you ! =)